# insert 80 data records into your SQL database with the same ID number

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlsrv

I'd like to make a sql table something like

[image]this.

I want to insert 80 data records in my SQL databse with the same ID number.

How can i overcome this sql database?

Comment: Hi - what have you tried and what issues are you facing? As inserting data into a table is a relatively trivial exercise, I assume there is more to your question than there appears?

Comment: Please add the table definition as text. sql does not store data in the format published you need to produce that in your presentation layer. You will need 80 inserts to load the data each insert loading 1 row containing id, serial_number, result1, result2 and result3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a *row generator*?

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
        ID INT,
        SN VARCHAR(20),
        RESULT1 VARCHAR(2),
        RESULT2 VARCHAR(2),
        RESULT3 VARCHAR(2)
    );
```

`INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, SN, RESULT1, RESULT2, RESULT3) 
WITH RECURSIVE seq AS 
  (SELECT 'I' result, 0 AS value 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'I' result, value + 1 FROM seq LIMIT 80
  )
SELECT 1, 'PKR123456789', result, result, result FROM seq;
```

Check what's being inserted:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cio3m8hq) session, if you want to have a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2iyUuEg2ZOM ?

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
        ID INT DEFAULT 1,
        SN VARCHAR DEFAULT 'PKR123...',
        RESULT1 VARCHAR,
        RESULT2 VARCHAR,
        RESULT3 VARCHAR
    );
    INSERT INTO mytable (RESULT1, RESULT2, RESULT3) VALUES ('I', 'I', 'I');
    INSERT INTO mytable (RESULT1, RESULT2, RESULT3) VALUES ('I', 'I', 'I');
    INSERT INTO mytable (RESULT1, RESULT2, RESULT3) VALUES ('I', 'I', 'I');
    INSERT INTO mytable (RESULT1, RESULT2, RESULT3) VALUES ('I', 'I', 'I');
    select * from mytable
```

Comment: What if i will insert another new 80 data ?

Comment: You'll insert another 80 data.